# How SSO is working with OKTA

Tags: single-sign-on, okta

Am trying to build few application that uses OKTA as IdP and utilizes OKTA-SSO.

I have seen the OKTA Music Store application that uses our okta Id as login id. 
How can I build / what changes i need to make in new C# web apps so that SSO works.

If some sample project or links would be helpful

Answer (score 3):

You have several options when adding SSO to an Okta application. The easiest method would be to add support for WS-Fed to your application. See Okta's guide to [Configuring the Okta Template WS Federation Application](https://support.okta.com/help/articles/Knowledge_Article/29510977-Configuring-the-Okta-Template-WS-Federation-Application) for more details on that.

Another option would be to add support SAML. However, how you add SAML support your application depends a lot on how your application models users and entitlements. Okta has [high level guidance for Single Sign-On with Okta](http://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/saml_guidance.html) that can help you plan for adding SAML support. For .NET Framework 4.5 or above, Okta recommends the [Kentor Authentication Services](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices#kentor-authentication-services) package. For .NET Framework 4 or below, Okta recommends [ComponentSpace SAML 2.0](http://www.componentspace.com/SAMLv20.aspx)

Comment: will check this and let u know

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider doing some of it yourself (via OIDC) - for some part building upon the 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager', 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfiguration' & 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler' classes, and some OP (OIDC Provider) endpoint calls using the 'HttpClient' class.

I believe involving NuGet packages such as:

```
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" version="6.7.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="6.7.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" version="6.7.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" version="6.7.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="6.7.1" targetFramework="net472" />
```

Be mindful to also include the use of the PKCE (Proof Key for Code Exchange / 'pixie') extension on top of the (OAuth) 'Authorisation Code' flow.